# How to minimize(iconify) FXML app?

Tags: java, events, user-interface, javafx

How can i assign a handler to minimize(iconify) app to a `@FXML private HBox minBtn;` (custom button made with Shape) button from Controller's `public void initialize(URL, ResourceBundle)` method? `setIconified(boolean)` method is in Stage class and i can't get him in my Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the Stage by

```
minBtn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
        ((Stage) ((Node) arg0.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).setIconified(true);
        // OR
        ((Stage) minBtn.getScene().getWindow()).setIconified(true);
    }
});
```