# Removing Focus from Java FX pane

Tags: java, javafx, pane

I'm trying to make my own GUI like thing with Java FX, but I can't seem to find a way to get a minimize button to work. I don't have the menu at the top of the screen, so you can't just use that. Is there any way to make it happen, or is this just a lost cause?

Comment: your question is about removing focus or minimizing? for both there are discussions on here. Try search them first.

Comment: @ulukbiy I didn't see any with a sufficient answer, and none seemed to be the way I was doing mine, but yes. I do mean minimizing. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/q/11526107/682495](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11526107/682495)